# Nativescript : Custom component slow response and problem with module global access

Tags: nativescript, custom-component

I am using ‘Music Streaming App template’ From Nativescript Marketplace, I made few updates, I separated the footer in custom module called 'footer-menu' and trying to use it in ‘home’ and ‘artist’ html pages by calling  at the end of each page.
This is a link for current code on ‘Playground’
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ERHBrE&v=130
I have two issues:

First: 
When I click on any footer link, it takes very long time to respond, and sometimes I have to click twice for the action to take place and navigate to another page!
Second: 
I want to call the custom component  in other components. To do that I want to import the ‘Footer-menu’ module/component only in one place ‘app.module.ts’ and use it in all the other components, but it is not working! 
I had to import it to each module to work!.
So why it is not seen while in ‘app.module.ts’?

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ERHBrE&v=130

When importing the module in 'app.module.ts' it never works. for that I had to import it to every module I want to call it from.
I just want to call it in app.module.ts and use it everywhere.
Besides function calls from footer is not responding all the time, and it is very slow why?

Comment: In my opinion there are scope for improvements, Use a TabView instead of loading new pages every time when you tap on the items in footer menu, so you won't have to create new pages every time. Also use ListView / RadListView instead of ScrollView with actual Views which is bad and may take long time to render comparatively - are to name few.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable notes, I will follow them.
But I still want to know why the footer is not working when including its module in app.module.ts!

Comment: I think the footer still works, only that it becomes too slow to respond to the navigation. I believe using TabView may greatly improve the experience as you are rendering new pages every time now.